# Solution for CA2227 or better approach?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

I'm only using Code Analysis for cleaning, organizing and ensuring these changes are globally performed for all instances of a particular warning. I'm down to the final, and it's CA2227.

> CA2227    Collection properties should be read only   Change '' to be
>   read-only by removing the property setter.

*Note this is for mapping of EDI documents. These classes are to represent a whole or part of an EDI document.*

```
public class PO1Loop
{

    public SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PO1 PO1 { get; set; }

    public Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PID1> PIDRepeat1 { get; set; }

    public Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PID2> PIDRepeat2 { get; set; }

    public SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PO4 PO4 { get; set; }

    /* Max Use: 8 */
    public Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.ACK> ACKRepeat { get; set; }

}
```

You can see all of the Collection properties will give me this warning, and there are hundreds of them. When using the above class I instantiate it without any data. Then externally I add the data and set each individual variable through its public accessor. I do not instantiate this class with all the data prepared and passed using a constructor method (IMO for the size these can reach it can easily wreak havoc on the eyes). When complete and all properties are assigned the class as a whole is then used to generate that part of a document it represents.

My question is, for the usage described above, what would be a better approach for setting this up correctly? Do I keep the public accessors and suppress this warning entirely, or is there a entirely different solution that would work?

Comment: What is setting the properties?  Can you make the setters `private` or `internal`? If not I would just suppress the warning.

Comment: Do you actually set them as `PO1Loop.PIDRepeat1 = new Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PID1>();` outside the class? If you are just `adding`, `removing`, or `altering` elements within the collections, then remove the unnecessary `set`.

Comment: You could just expose public getters and do an `AddRange` on them when you have the values.  A better option would be to ignore this suggestion.

Comment: The MSDN page for that error give the rationale behind it and a suggestion for how to implement to avoid it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @EBrown I am settings outside the class. The idea is to have a library of components that make up a particular set of EDI documents. From the project that handles and generates these documents is where it gets "populated"

Comment: Right, but do you actually need to run the *constructor* for the `Collection` there?

Comment: @CraigW So the idea would be to instantiate this class, and therefore the collections themselves in the constructor (they will never be null). Then outside where they populate simply use .AddRange, .Clear etc?

Comment: @EBrown No, but I did so because the types vary in only two ways, either simply a defined object, or collection of defined objects, all of which are null if they are not used when generating a documents context. I suppose it was done for easier copy and pasting...

Comment: @DavidCarrigan: Yes, that is correct. IMO a collection should never be null. It might be empty, but never null.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's what [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says about the error, and also how you can avoid it.

Here's my take on the issue.

Consider, the following class:

```
class BigDataClass
{
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

This class will throw that exact same issue. Why? Because `Collections` do **not** need a setter. Now, we can do **anything** with that object: assign `Data` to an arbitrary `List<string>`, add elements to `Data`, remove elements from `Data`, etc. If we remove the `setter`, we **only** lose the ability to *directly assign to that property.*

Consider the following code:

```
class BigDataClass
{
    private List<string> data = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Data { get { return data; } } // note, we removed the setter
}

var bigData = new BigDataClass();
bigData.Data.Add("Some String");
```

This code is **perfectly valid** and in fact **the recommended way to do things**. Why? Because the `List<string>` is a *reference* to a memory location, that contains the remainder of the data.

Now, the *only* thing you cannot now do with this, is *directly set* the `Data` property. I.e. the following is invalid:

```
var bigData = new BigDataClass();
bigData.Data = new List<string>();
```

This is *not necessarily* a bad thing. You'll notice that on *many* .NET types this model is used. It's the basics of immutability. You *usually* do not want direct access to the mutability of `Collections`, as this can cause some accidental behavior that has strange issues. This is why Microsoft recommends you omit setters.

Example:

```
var bigData = new BigDataClass();
bigData.Data.Add("Some String");
var l2 = new List<string>();
l2.Add("String 1");
l2.Add("String 2");
bigData.Data = l2;
Console.WriteLine(bigData.Data[0]);
```

We might be expecting `Some String`, but we'll get `String 1`. This also means that you *cannot reliably attach events* to the `Collection` in question, so you *cannot reliably determine if new values are added or values are removed.*

> A writable collection property allows a user to replace the collection with a completely different collection.

Essentially, if you only *ever* need to run the constructor, or assignment, once, then omit the `set` modifier. You won't need it, direct assignment of collections is against best-practices.

Now, I'm not saying *never use a setter* on a `Collection`, sometimes you may need one, but in general you should not use them.

You can always use `.AddRange`, `.Clone`, etc. on the `Collections`, you **only** lose the ability of `direct assignment`.

### Serialization

Lastly, what do we do if we wish to `Serialize` or `Deserialize` a class that contains our `Collection` without a `set`? Well, there is always more than one way to do it, the simplest (in my opinion) is to create a `property` that represents the serialized collection.

Take our `BigDataClass` for example. If we wished to `Serialize`, and then `Deserialize` this class with the following code, the `Data` property would have no elements.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
BigDataClass bdc = new BigDataClass();
bdc.Data.Add("Test String");
string serd = jss.Serialize(bdc);
Console.WriteLine(serd);
BigDataClass bdc2 = jss.Deserialize<BigDataClass>(serd);
```

So, to fix this, we can simply modify our `BigDataClass` a bit to make it use a new `string` property for `Serialization` purposes.

```
public class BigDataClass
{
    private List<string> data = new List<string>();
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public List<string> Data { get { return data; } } // note, we removed the setter

    public string SerializedData { get { JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); return jss.Serialize(data); } set { JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer(); data = jss.Deserialize<List<string>>(value); } }
}
```

Another option is always the `DataContractSerializer` (which is really a better option, in general.) You can find information about it on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961019/json-deserialise-to-an-object-with-a-private-setter).

Comment: Thanks this did help ease my troubled feeling about this solution being implemented in my fashion. I feel more comfortable in that it's the proper way to work with immutable types..

Comment: @DavidCarrigan It is, and I'll post examples of serializing collection attributes when I get home from work. That should also ease some of your feelings of the subject.

Comment: @DavidCarrigan I added information about serializing such objects.

Comment: That's an interesting tidbit on serialization, actually helped me with another project. I feel your solutions here can scale easily while avoiding maintenance nightmares. Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidCarrigan Not a problem. I tend to over-answer for reasons like that. Glad you found all of this helpful.

Comment: @EBrown, are we supposed to have that logic in all DTO classes that need to be serialised/deserialised?

Comment: @Bomboca I don't know what the "best-practice" is for this, I do know that this method has worked successfully for me in the past. I'm not a .NET expert so there may be built-in functionality to address this situation.

Comment: Resolving a warning is not worth giving up serialization abstraction. There must be a better way to do this, otherwise suppressing the warning is probably the best way.

Comment: @FlorianWinter One way to get immutability without breaking serialization now is to use init only properties, available in .net 5/C# 9.0 or later - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald Thank you. This solves something that has been bugging me for a long time: Having to add "write-only" properties to client-side API models, because these properties are set by the server in responses but cannot be sent back to the server in requests.

Answer (score 17):

With current VS2019 we can simply do this:

```
public List<string> Data { get; } = new List<string>();
```

This satisfies CA2227 and can be serialized/deserialized.

The deserialization works because List<> has an "Add" method, and the serializer knows how to handle a read-only collection property with an Add method (the property is read-only but not the elements) (I use Json.Net, other serializers may behave differently).

**Edit:**
*As pointed out it should be "=" and not "=>" (compiler will prevent you using "=>"). If we used "public List Data => new List();" then it would create a new list every time the property was accessed which is not what we want either.*

**Edit:**
Note that this will NOT work if the type of the property is an interface, such as `IList`

**Edit:**
I think the handling of interfaces is determined by the serializer used. The following works perfectly. I'm sure all common serializers know how to handle ICollection. And if you have some custom interface that does not implement ICollection then you should be able to configure the serializer to handle it, but in that case CA2227 probably won't be triggered making it irrelevant here. (*As it is a read-only property you have to assign a concrete value within the class so it should always be serializing and de-serializing a non-null value*)

```
    public class CA2227TestClass
    {
        public IList Data { get; } = new List<string>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CA2227_Serialization()
    {
        var test = new CA2227TestClass()
        {
            Data = { "One", "Two", "Three" }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);

        Assert.AreEqual("{\"Data\":[\"One\",\"Two\",\"Three\"]}", json);

        var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(CA2227TestClass)) as CA2227TestClass;

        Assert.IsNotNull(jsonObject);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, jsonObject.Data.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("One", jsonObject.Data[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Two", jsonObject.Data[1]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Three", jsonObject.Data[2]);
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(List<string>), jsonObject.Data.GetType());
    }
```

Comment: I used this, thanks for the help, but it took me a while to figure out that `=>` should be `=`

Comment: Works with VS2017 too.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternative Solution**

In my situation, making the property read-only was not viable because the whole list (*as a reference*) could change to a new list.

I was able to resolve this warning by changing the properties' setter scope to be `internal`.

```
public List<Batch> Batches
{
    get { return _Batches; }
    internal set { _Batches = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Batches)); }
}
```

*Note one could also use `private set`...*

---

The hint's (*achilleas heal*) of this warning seems really pointed to libraries for the documentation says (Bolding mine):

> An **externally visible** writable property is a type that implements
>   System.Collections.ICollection.

For me it was, "Ok, I won't make it viewable externally...." and `internal` was fine for the app.

Answer (score 2):

Only while binding DTO, you need to suppress warnings.
otherwise a custom ModelBinder is required custom ModelBinder to bind collections.

quoting the rule documentation:

> **When to suppress warnings**
>
> You can suppress the warning if the property is part of a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class.
> Otherwise, do not suppress warnings from this rule.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2227?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Matthew, @CraigW and @EBrown for helping me understanding the solution for this warning.

```
public class PO1Loop
{

    public SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PO1 PO1 { get; set; }

    public Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PID1> PIDRepeat1 { get; private set; }

    public Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PID2> PIDRepeat2 { get; private set; }

    public SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PO4 PO4 { get; set; }

    /* Max Use: 8 */
    public Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.ACK> ACKRepeat { get; private set; }

    public PO1Loop()
    {
        PIDRepeat1 = new Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PID1>();
        PIDRepeat2 = new Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.PID2>();
        ACKRepeat = new Collection<SegmentTypes.PO1LoopSegmentTypes.ACK>();
    }

}
```

When wanting to assign data to the collection types use AddRange, Clear or any other variation of method for modifying a collection.

Answer (score 1):

DTOs often require serialization and deserialization. Thus, they are required to be mutable.

Having to create an alternate backing property is a pain.
Simply change the property type from `List<string>` to `IReadOnlyList<string>` then this works as expected without CA2227.

The collection is set via the property but you can also cast to `List<string>` if you wish to append or delete items.

```
class Holder
{
    public IReadOnlyList<string> Col { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

var list = new List<string> { "One", "Two" };
var holder = new Holder() { Col = list } ;
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(holder);
// output json {"Col":["One","Two"]}
var deserializedHolder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Holder>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to *Der Kommissar*'s excellent answer.

Starting with .NET 5 (C# 9.0) there are [init-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init). These properties are only settable under specific circumstances, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init#init-accessors) for reference.

The following example should not raise a warning CA2227, yet still allow for the collection being set during object initialization.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BookStore
{
    public class BookModel
    {
        public ICollection<string> Chapters { get; init; }
    }
}
```

*Note that the current version of the .NET SDK still raises a warning when using the built-in analyzer (not the NuGet package). This is a known bug and should be fixed in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix some of the CA2227 violations, so i had to add the "readonly" keyword to the collection field and then of course, had to remove the setter property. Some code that have used the setter, just created a new collection object which initially was empty. This code sure did not compile so i had to add a SetXxx() method in order to realize the missing setter's functionality. I did it like this:

```
public void SetXxx(List<string> list)
{
    this.theList.Clear();
    this.theList.AddRange(list);
}
```

The code of callers using the setter has been replaced with a call to the method SetXxx().

Instead of creating a complete new list, the existing list now will be cleared and filled with new items from another list, passed in as a parameter. The original list, due to the fact it is readonly and created only once, will always remain.

I believe this is also a good way to avoid that the garbagae collector has to delete old objects that got out of scope and second, to create new collection objects although there is already one.

Answer (score -1):

**To cover all the possible scenarios to resolve CA2227 error:**
This covers the Entity relationship mapping when we use Entity Framework.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ParentClass obj = new ParentClass();

        obj.ChildDetails.Clear();
        obj.ChildDetails.AddRange();

        obj.LstNames.Clear();
        obj.LstNames.AddRange();


    }


}
public class ChildClass
{ }
public class ParentClass
{
    private readonly ICollection<ChildClass> _ChildClass;
    public ParentClass()
    {
        _ChildClass = new HashSet<ChildClass>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ChildClass> ChildDetails => _ChildClass;
    public IList<string> LstNames => new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain your answer better.