# access collection as read-only property and nice instance creation

Tags: c#, .net

The purpose of using ReadOnly collections is discussed here: [Solution for CA2227 or better approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30359978/solution-for-ca2227-or-better-approach)

My question is if there is a way not to make the code "ugly" by using the new initializer of c#.

For example we have the following code

```
                return new User
                {
                    Firstname = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Constants.ClaimTypes.UserFirstname)?.Value,
                    Lastname = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Constants.ClaimTypes.UserLastname)?.Value,
                    LogonName = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Constants.ClaimTypes.UserLogon)?.Value,
                    Roles = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Constants.ClaimTypes.UserRoles)?.Value.Split(";#").ToList()
                };
```

When the model for `Roles` is

```
public List<string> Roles { get; } = new List<string>();
```

the above code won't work because we cannot assign a new List to Roles.

Is there a way to `return new User` without blowing up the code? Shure I could create an initializer method in the User class but this makes the `new User(...)` call cluttered

Comment: For clarity: is the collection read-only or is the property get-only?

Comment: When there are actual collections with `ReadOnly` in their name - [`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-5.0), it's best to avoid such capitalisation when you're not actually talking about those. As Llama says, this appears to be a read-only property.

Comment: Thanks for the clearance. I've changed the title

Comment: You could make use of a public, static `FromClaims` method in the `User` class. Seems like all your properties are based on a `claim`. You'd still have to assign the values as above but only once and not every time you're creating a new `User`.

Comment: `user.Roles.AddRange(claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Constants.ClaimTypes.UserRoles)?.Value.Split(";#"));` ?